# Limit the number of words according to the user input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript code of generating keywords when user enter a keyword in the textarea.How can i limit the number of words in each line of search results according to the user input?? as example if user input cat and number of words as 2 it should generate the results like this...
catheter heart
catheter hub
catheter hurts
catheter holder

```
<div class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-9" align="left">
    <textarea id="filter-positive" rows="4" onkeyup="FilterIfNotWorking()" placeholder="Positive Filter"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <textarea id="filter-negative" rows="4" onkeyup="FilterIfNotWorking()" placeholder="Negative Filter"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
    <textarea id="number of rows" rows="4" onkeyup="NumberOfWords()" placeholder="Number of words"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your query or how you're filtering/restricting/search results actually?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.Here it is

Comment: <div class="grid__col grid__col--1-of-9" align="left">
            <textarea id="filter-positive" rows="4" onkeyup="FilterIfNotWorking()" placeholder="Positive Filter"></textarea>
            <br>
            <br>
            <textarea id="filter-negative" rows="4" onkeyup="FilterIfNotWorking()" placeholder="Negative Filter"></textarea>
   <br>
   <br>
   <textarea id="number of rows" rows="4" onkeyup="NumberOfWords()" placeholder="Number of words"></textarea>
        </div>

Comment: http://directmarketleads.com/keyword.htm

Comment: http://directmarketleads.com/keyword.htm

Comment: take a look at the above link

Comment: I am not sure how you're generating these words, one quick approach is to check the words count for each generated string and filter it accordingly

Comment: Can i set the limit of words to the text area???

Comment: Can  directly get the user input and set it here
<textarea id="number of rows" rows="4" onkeyup="NumberOfWords()" placeholder="Number of words"></textarea>

Comment: no , you can't. You need to filter your results in startjob js function

Comment: Please can you tell me how??

Comment: function StartJob()
        {     
            if(doWork == false)
            {     
                keywordsToDisplay = new Array();
                hashMapResults = {}; 
                keywordsToQuery = new Array();
                keywordsToQueryIndex = 0; 
                
                hashMapResults[""] = 1; 
                hashMapResults[" "] = 1; 
                hashMapResults["  "] = 1; 
                
                var ks = $('#input').val().split("\n");
                var i = 0;

Comment: In your QueryKeyword method , on success check the length of the words to filter them out

Comment: Can you just rephrase what you are doing and what you actually want to do

Comment: just looked at your code, You can add this logic into the Filter method where you are already filtering for positive and negative filters

Comment: should i add another method?

Comment: @Nipuna Please edit your question with properly formatted code instead of posting it in the comments. It makes it much easier for people to answer. Thanks!

Comment: may be add an extra check in existing loop

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to filter or restrict Java script arrays data. You can add an extra piece of code in your Filter method as follows

```
 function Filter(listToFilter)
  {
     for (i = 0; i < retList.length; i++)
     {
       var currentKeyword = retList[i];
       if(currentKeyword.split(' ').length <= 2) {
              //TODO: add in addition array or continue the loop to filter this word our or other way around
       }
    }
}
```